# Cannot access a site without www

Tags: url, cloudflare

I have my site and the hosting was on GoDaddy and I changed it to CloudFlare .. Previously, you could access the Via site just writing **example.com** or **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

But after changed the Hosting, the site does not open and you must enter **www**

Comment: This is actually a cloudflare support question. It belongs there. With that said, you might find some info here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/site-wont-load-without-www/12096/2

Answer (score 0):

By saying you changed your site from Godaddy hosting to Cloudflare, what do you mean?

Plus, there are a few possible cases in which this could happen.

1. The SSL Certificate configuration you have active on the site. I do not mean Cloudflare Native certificate (This might not be a reason that would occur always)
2. Your .htaccess configuration (There should be something that is redirecting your site)

Kindly check these and see if it helps

Comment: changed DNS..  the site from Godaddy to DNS of Cloud Flare